# Derive curl of vector field in spherical coordinates

Tags: vector-fields, spherical-coordinates, curl

I need to calculate curl of $F$, and show that it is conservative on this region.

A vector field $F$, defined on a simply-connected region $r > 0,\; \frac{\pi}{4}< \theta < \frac{3 \pi}{4},\; \frac{- \pi}{2}< \phi < \frac{ \pi}{2}$ is expressed in spherical coordinates as:

$$F(r, \theta, \epsilon) \;=\; \sin(\phi) \cos(\theta) e_r - \sin(\phi)\sin(\theta) e_\theta + \cos(\phi)cot(\theta) e_\phi.$$

**Curl in spherical coordinates:**

$$\nabla * F \;=\; (\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial F \phi}{\partial \theta} - \frac{1}{r\sin(\theta)}\frac{\partial F \theta}{\partial \phi} + \frac{\cot(\theta)}{r}F \phi)e_r \\ + (-\frac{\partial F \phi}{\partial r} - \frac{1}{r\sin(\theta)}\frac{\partial F r}{\partial \phi} - \frac{1}{r}F \phi)e_\theta \\
+ (\frac{\partial F \theta}{\partial r} - \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial F r}{\partial \theta} + \frac{1}{r}F \theta)e_\phi.$$

**My workings using the above:**

$\nabla * F$ = $(-\frac{\csc^2(\theta)\cos(\phi)}{r}-\frac{\cos(\phi)}{r}+\frac{\cos(\phi)\cot^2(\theta)}{r})e_r$ +

$(-0 +\frac{\cos(\phi)\cos(\theta)}{r\sin(\theta} - \frac{\sin(\phi)\sin(\theta)}{r})e_\theta$ +

$(0+ \frac{\sin(\phi)\sin(\theta)}{r}+\frac{\sin(\phi)\sin(\theta)}{r})e_\phi$

Is this correct? Am I missing some identities that would express this in a much simpler way? I've left in the zero values. And if it is correct, how do I begin to find out whether it's conservative? I'm expecting a question like this in an exam I have soon, so I need a pretty quick method of being able to calculate curl and whether it's conservative.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How about: convert to Cartesian coordinates and compute there?

Comment: @Calvin Khor thanks, I could do that. I'm looking for the most straight forward, quickest method of solving this type of problem. It's been a while since I've converted to and from Cartesian/Spherical, so I'll have to give it a go later tonight and see how quick I can manage it.

In the mean time, any input on my workings thus far?

Comment: Conceptually looks ok to me

Comment: I just woke up and tried converting to cartesian and I don't think its much easier. I think just do what you're doing. to show its conservative, you can show its a gradient. One way to do that is to show that its curl is zero. So check the second curl of $F$?

Comment: @ Clavin Khor I also tried converting to Cartesian coordinates - far too time consuming without providing significant clarity; I'm expected to answer a question like this in less than 6 minutes. I think I'm just going to have to pass for now and ask my lecturer. Thanks for the help.